# are POD given special treatment when default initializing (c++14)?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Why following code produced 0 as output? In my understanding, it is default initialization (not value initialization) so value should be random.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>

using namespace std;

struct A 
{

    int i;
    int j;
};


int main()
{
    A a;

    cout << " i is " << a.i << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

from cppreference:

The effects of default initialization are:

if T is a non-POD (until C++11) class type, the constructors are considered and subjected to overload resolution against the empty argument list. The constructor selected (which is one of the default constructors) is called to provide the initial value for the new object;

if T is an array type, every element of the array is default-initialized;

otherwise, nothing is done: the objects with automatic storage duration (and their subobjects) are initialized to indeterminate values.

Comment: Can't 0 be drawn in a random draw?

Comment: isnt `0` as random as any other number?

Comment: Why do you think, that `0` is an invalid random value?

Comment: its a common misunderstanding in c++ that if there is a red traffic light telling you not to cross the street, that there **must** be a car crossing your path. The reality is: the red light just tells you that there **might be** a car crossing your path, so unless you want to take the risk you better go with green

Comment: Since `a` fields are not initialized you are just getting an Undefined Behavior.

Comment: What happens is that the structure object `a` is placed somewhere in memory, and the values of `i` and `j` reflects what's in that memory. You will not know what's in that memory beforehand, which leads to their values being *indeterminate*, not "random" (even though it might seem like that sometimes).

Comment: Cannot confirm http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=600713a1041e98eb

Comment: I tried with difference compiler combinations and got everywhere same 0. A random number can not be so certain!!

Comment: @setia_ see the link I posted

Comment: i tried various online ide, it gave 0 everywhere gcc is used. for clang compiler it gave random. seems gcc and clang behavior is different.

Comment: @setia_ Undefined behavior it's just that - undefined. It can just, seem to work, as you expected, in every case, for yourself, except for when you try to show it to your boss.. You can't expect anything, from,  the thing that is undefined.

Comment: @setia_ Your expectation of getting a random value is wrong on the first place. You can not even expect this code to print anything.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I wanted to clear my understanding. I understand that this is by luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What value you get for `a.i` is not defined, you should expect to get any value.

Depening on the system, the used std library, the compiler, the compiler flags, ... some parts of the memory (e.g. the stack) might be initialized with `0`, but there is no guarantee for that.

This is also true for `gcc`, in your simple example your might always get `0`, but if you turn off optimizations `-O0` and compile the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A 
{
  int i;
  int j;
};


int foo() {
  A a;
  const int b = a.i;
  a.i = 123;
  return b;
}

int main() {
  const int n1 = foo();
  const int n2 = foo();
  std::cout << n1 << " " << n2 << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Then  (depending on the os, std library, cpu ...) you will have the following output:

```
0 123
```

In both cases `a.i` is uninitialized, for the first call the `a.i` holds some *"random"* number, for the second call, `a` might be created at the same location, and as of that this part of the memory might still hold `123`. The reason for that is that `A` is created on the stack, and the subsequent calls to off `foo` will most likely cause `a` to be located on the same memory address on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Based on discussion, experiment. It is undefined behavior. POD have no special treatment in default initialization.

clang, MSVC always gave random value but gcc always gave 0. Afterall, undefined is undefined.